# How can I plot a cat in Matplotlib using voxels?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, voxel

I don't have much experience on Python 3.8 neither on Matplotlib. I am trying to plot a Big Cube made of little transparent voxels, and some opaque ones

This is the code I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# This import registers the 3D projection, but is otherwise unused.
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  # noqa: F401 unused import

# prepare some coordinates
x, y, z = np.indices((8, 8, 8))

# draw cuboids transparent cuboids and opaque cuboids
transparent_cubes = (x < 8) & (y < 8) & (z < 8)
opaque_cubes_1 = ( x < 2) & (y == 0 ) & (z == 3)
opaque_cubes_2 = ( x == 5) & (y == 5 ) & (z == 5)

# combine the objects into a single boolean array
voxels1 = transparent_cubes
voxels2 = opaque_cubes_1 | opaque_cubes_2

# set the colors of each object
colors1 = np.empty(voxels1.shape, dtype=object)
colors1[transparent_cubes] = 'white'


colors2 = np.empty(voxels2.shape, dtype=object)
colors2[opaque_cubes_1] = 'red'
colors2[opaque_cubes_2] = 'red'

# and plot everything
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.voxels(voxels1, facecolors=colors1, edgecolor='none', alpha=0.4)
ax.voxels(voxels2, facecolors=colors2, edgecolor='none')

plt.show()
```

And this is the plot generated:
[image]

But then, I was thinking, if I increase the coordinates, How can I plot more complex shapes?, for example, this one:

[image]

What would be the best approach to do this? Doing it cuboid by cuboid might be diffult, and I don't know what are the exactly coordinates of each voxel. So, any Ideas?

Comment: I would be tempted to use the 3D printer approach. For example, for each `z` starting from the ground, you could define a 2D array of size `x * y` that you fill with colors. Then we could probably find a way to make the empty sections of the array (defined by being `== 0` or `nan` maybe) fully transparent.

Comment: But, How do I know what are values that I need to use to plot the cat?

Comment: Unless you have something better than the image, we have to reconstruct the data by looking at it. Imagine the origin is at the right rear paw, we would have a something like A[0, 0, 0] = dark grey, A[0, 0, 1] = light grey, A[2, 0, 0] = empty or nan or 0 or transparent color.